# Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here

Tags: angular, lumen

I am trying to make a login service using the lumen for my backend. In postman it works as expected, but when I try to send the form data using the `onSubmit` function, it answers with a 200 but returns html instead of the api token. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
/* lUMEN API LOGIN CONTROLLER */
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {

      $rules = [
          'email' => 'required',
          'password' => 'required'
      ];

        $customMessages = [
           'required' => ':attribute tidak boleh kosong'
      ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
         $email    = $request->input('email');
        try {
            $login = User::where('email', $email)->first();
            if ($login) {
                if ($login->count() > 0) {
                    if (Hash::check($request->input('password'), $login->password)) {
                        try {
                            $api_token = sha1($login->id_user.time());

                              $create_token = User::where('id', $login->id_user)->update(['api_token' => $api_token]);
                              $res['status'] = true;
                              $res['message'] = 'Success login';
                              $res['data'] =  $login;
                              $res['api_token'] =  $api_token;

                              return response($res, 200);


                        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
                            $res['status'] = false;
                            $res['message'] = $ex->getMessage();
                            return response($res, 500);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $res['success'] = false;
                        $res['message'] = 'Username / email / password not found';
                        return response($res, 401);
                    }
                } else {
                    $res['success'] = false;
                    $res['message'] = 'Username / email / password  not found';
                    return response($res, 401);
                }
            } else {
                $res['success'] = false;
                $res['message'] = 'Username / email / password not found';
                return response($res, 401);
            }
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
            $res['success'] = false;
            $res['message'] = $ex->getMessage();
            return response($res, 500);
        }
    }
}
/* Angular Login Component */
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.less']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any = [ ];
  constructor(private api: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


onSubmit() {
  this.api.login(this.user).subscribe(
    data => {
      if (false) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.user));
    } else {
      console.log(this.user);
     }
    },

 );
 }
}
/* Angular login Service*/
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EnvService } from '../services/env.service';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
              public env: EnvService) { }

              login(user) {
                return this.http.post(this.env.LOCAL_ENDPOINT + '/login',  user, {responseType: 'text'});
                  }
            logout() {
                // remove user from local storage to log user out
                localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
            }
}
```

```html
<div class="uk-position-center">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div clsss="uk-card">
    <div class="uk-card-content">
      <form name="login" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <input placeholder="Email" class="uk-input" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email">
      <br/>
      <input placeholder="password" class="uk-input" type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
      <hr class="uk-divider-icon">
      
      <button style="align-content: center" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the response I get in the browser so I know that im not passing the data through the wright way but I have no idea what the correct way is 
[image: Web response]

This is the response I want to show and save the api token in local storage 
[image]

Network console
[image]

Comment: did you check  to see if you are send the data to the server correctly, inspect your network console

Comment: seems like your are posting username and password as formdata instead of passing it as query param.

Comment: I've updated it to show the network console but I don't think I am sending the data correctly but I don't know what way i'm men't to do it ive looked at http client videos and still its not working

Comment: in postman check if the backend works if the data is send in  form data or json instead of query param, you are passing the data in url which is not good

Comment: In postman it returns in json

Comment: console log your `this.user` and check  the data type and post a sample data here

Answer (score 0):

Like @Joel said, the problem is that the backend expects username and password as query params. You may edit your login service like so:

```
this.http.post( this.env.LOCAL_ENDPOINT + '/login?user=' + user.email + "&password=" + user.password, { responseType: 'text' } );
```

However, sending passwords as plaintext in the URL is very bad practice, so you I suggest you reconsider, and instead change the backend so that it expects username and pass in the header.

Comment: How would I pass it in the header

Comment: You can see a very good guide on the official angular site here: https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers. However, I don't know how you can modify your backend for this. My advice would be to find a tutorial that explains how to do the entire login process, both frontend and backend. If you don't, it's very likely that you will end up with security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

as per your postman screen shot the backend works when you are sending the data as query param  but you should be sending it as form data instead.

```
login(user){
   let userData = new FormData();
   userData.append('email', user.email);
   userData.append('password', user.password);
   return this.http.post(this.env.LOCAL_ENDPOINT + '/login',userData);
}
```